# Conditionally show a card component in React only when all the data/ images have loaded?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React but I have managed to get React to render a card component based on data from PokeAPI (the data itself is passed down to the component through props). The issue is that when the data changes (e.g user makes a new search) that data loads at different times, especially images which take a while to update.

I have looked at various solutions for conditionally rendering the card or a spinner/ loading text, including `onload` and `useRef` but due to my limited understanding and likely messy code I have not been able to get any of them to work. I understand that solutions are likely to involve setting a loading state but I have struggled to ascertain where exactly to set it.

I am sure there are many other issues with my code but I would hugely appreciate any help with this problem in particular.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

// Icon imports here
...

// Background imports here
...

function PokeCard(props) {
  const {pokeObj} = props
  const {pokemon, species, abilities} = pokeObj

  const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
  const [bgImage, setBgImage] = useState('')
  const [typeIcon, setTypeIcon] = useState('')
  const [circleColor, setCircleColor] = useState('')

  const [abilityArray, setAbilityArray] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(pokeObj){
      if(pokemon.id>905){
        return
      }

      const flavorArray = species.flavor_text_entries
      const desc = flavorArray.filter(flavor => flavor.language.name==='en')
      let formattedDesc = desc[0].flavor_text
        .replace('',' ')
        .replace('­\n', '')
        .replace(/\b[A-Z]+\b/g, (word) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase())
      setDescription(formattedDesc)

      const getTypeDecoration = () => {
        let bg
        let circ
        let icon
        switch (pokemon.types[0].type.name){
          case 'bug':
            bg = (bgGreen)
            circ = ("bg-green-700")
            icon = (FaBug)
            break
         // Other cases here
         ...
              
        }
        setBgImage(bg)
        setTypeIcon(icon)
        setCircleColor(circ)      
      }
      getTypeDecoration()

      setAbilityArray([])
      const newAbilities = []
      for (const a of abilities){
        const abilityObj ={}

        const abilityArr = a.names
        const name = abilityArr.filter(name => name.language.name==='en')
        abilityObj.abilityName=name[0].name

        const abilityFlavorArray = a.flavor_text_entries
        const desc = abilityFlavorArray.filter(flavor => flavor.language.name==='en')
        let formattedDesc = desc[0].flavor_text
          .replace(/\b[A-Z]+\b/g, (word) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase())
          .replace('Pp', 'PP')
          .replace('Hp', 'HP')
        abilityObj.abilityDescription=formattedDesc
        newAbilities.push(abilityObj)

        setAbilityArray(newAbilities)
        console.log('done')
        
      }
    }
    
  },[pokeObj])
  
  
    return (
        <div>
          {pokemon.id<=905 ?
            
            <div className="container mx-auto card-outer p-5 m-10 bg-yellow-300 rounded-3xl text-black font-futura w-96">
              <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bgImage})` }}className="card-inner p-3 bg-hero bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center">
                <div className="card-top flex text-2xl mx-3">
                  <div className="name grow text-3xl">{pokemon.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pokemon.name.slice(1)}</div> 
                  <div className="pokedexNumber text-orange-600 ">#{pokemon.id}</div>
                  <div className={`type-button w-fit h-fit p-1 rounded-full ml-1 ${circleColor}`}>
                    {typeIcon}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="picture-border-container mx-3 bg-gradient-to-br from-yellow-200 via-yellow-600 to-yellow-200 p-2 drop-shadow-md">
                  <div className="card-picture bg-orange-200 h-48">
                    <img className="h-full mx-auto" src={`${pokemon.sprites.other['official-artwork'].front_default}`} alt={pokemon.name} />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="under-image">
                  <div className="generation-box">
                    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="30 0 350 350" className="inline">
                      <defs>
                        <path id="MyPath"
                              d="M 200, 200
                                m -100, 0
                                a 100,100 0 1,1 200,0
                                a 100,100 0 1,1 -200,0" 
                        />
                      </defs>
                      <text className="text-[70px]">
                        <textPath xlinkHref="#MyPath">
                          GENERATION
                        </textPath>
                      </text>
                      <circle fill="black" cx="200" cy="200" r="80" strokeWidth="10" />
                      <text x="200" y="205"
                        textAnchor="middle"
                        stroke="white"
                        fill="white"
                        strokeWidth="1px"
                        alignmentBaseline="middle"
                        className="text-[90px]"        
                      > 
                        {species && species.generation.url.charAt(species.generation.url.length - 2)}
                      </text>
                    </svg>
                    <p className="info-strip inline-block bg-gradient-to-br from-yellow-600 via-yellow-400 to-yellow-600 w-60 italic text-xs text-center" >Height: {pokemon.height/10}m, Weight: {pokemon.weight/10}kg</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-4 h-[160px]">
                  {
                    abilityArray && abilityArray.map((a) => {
                      return (
                        <>
                          <div key={a.id} className="ability-box mx-10 h-20 flex items-center ">
                            <div className="ability-name inline text-lg leading-3">
                              {a.abilityName}
                              <span className="ability-desc text-sm pl-3">{a.abilityDescription}</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <hr className="border-1 border-black"/>
                        </>
                      )
                    })
                  }
                </div>         
                <div className="pokemon-description border-2 text-xs border-yellow-500 mx-3 leading-4 ">
                  {description}
                </div>
                <div className="copyright-info text-[10px] text-center">
                  Pokémon and Pokémon character names are trademarks of Nintendo.
                </div>
              </div>        
            </div>
            :
            find && <p>Oops! Couldn't find that Pokémon, sorry! </p>
          }        
        </div>
    )  
}

export default PokeCard
```